# Send an extra parameter with xml-rpc login?

Tags: xml-rpc

New to xml-rpc with wordpress. I am trying to add a 3rd login parameter for security reasons to the xml-rpc connection.

As it stands the default login only accepts a username and password. On our actual site I have added a "agent id" which is for internal employees and acts as an extra security layer. Is there a way to send something like an "agent id" so the request includes username, password, and agent id from xml-rpc that will make the login validate? If possible, please include a brief sample and explanation.